# Sort function does not sort my structure in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sorting

I have a structure defined below: I want the structure to be sorted by ascending order.

```
struct Share
{
   let firstColumn: String
   let secondColumn: String
   let thirdcolumn: String
   let FourthColumn: String
   init(firstColumn: String, secondColumn: String, thirdcolumn: String, FourthColumn: 
    String = "")
    {
        self.firstColumn = firstColumn
        self.secondColumn = secondColumn
        self.thirdcolumn = thirdcolumn
       self.FourthColumn = FourthColumn
    }
```

}

The all of the column's are numbers that are type casted to a string. All I want to do is sort the structure by the firstColumn.

I call this function below:

```
shares.sort(by:{ $0.firstColumn < $1.firstColumn })
```

But it does not sort the structure property.

[image]

Comment: Where does 'shares' come from?

Comment: its my structure share that I created called shares

Comment: It is sorting `firstColumn` as a `String`.

Comment: Should I changed the type to a Double then? Does sorting it as a String not work?

Comment: If you can change the type to Double in your structure, do so, otherwise try `shares.sort(by:{ Double($0.firstColumn) ?? 0 < Double($1.firstColumn) ?? 0 })`

Comment: Sorting as a `String` doesn't work because `1000.0` comes before `12.0` lexicographically.

Comment: oh i see. Thank you! Your suggestion work! Please answer the question so I can accept it

Comment: @Chris Why don't you change your property type and store them as Double?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sort isn't working as expected because you are sorting the `firstColumn` as a `String`.  When treated as a `String`, `1000.0` comes before `12.0` so you won't get the `firstColumn` sorted in numerical order.

If you can store your `firstColumn` as a `Double`, then do so.

Otherwise, you can convert the values while sorting with this:

```
shares.sort(by:{ Double($0.firstColumn) ?? 0 < Double($1.firstColumn) ?? 0 })
```

---

Note: Since not all `String`s can be converted to `Double`, the conversion returns a `Double?` that is `nil` when the conversion fails.  The *nil coalescing operator* `??` is used to replace the failed cases with `0`.  If you're sure all of the values will convert, then `??` just unwraps the converted value.

Answer (score 4):

You can also specify a `.numeric` option for `compare` of strings:

```swift
let results = shares.sorted {
    $0.firstColumn.compare($1.firstColumn, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending
}
```